# "Skip to..." in HTTP videos

Tags: javascript, http, video, html5-video

I want to allow my users to "Skip" to points in the video without needing them to buffer it before. For example, take a look at a Vimeo video in their HTML5 player (Open a video and click "Switch to HTML5 player"). As I see in a sniffing tool, they load the video normally, but when you click on a point in the timeline, it sends a request to the server, and it responds with a link that contains a special token.

Megavideo is doing it too.

Any ideas how to implement this into a HTTP video server?

Comment: see if this helps http://blog.gingertech.net/2009/08/19/jumping-to-time-offsets-in-videos/

Comment: Cut the video in the server and send it back to the page and put it back into the `<video>` tag.

Comment: @Derek, that is not what the OP is asking. The OP said he wants to do it like Megavideo and Vimeo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need implement 'range' support in your HTTP server. Most modern web servers have range support, 'out of the box'.

Relevant headers:

- [Accept-Ranges](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.5)
- [Content-Range](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.16)
- [Range](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35)
- [If-Range](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.27)

Relevant response codes:

- [206 Partial Content](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.7)
- [416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.17)

Relevant data types:

- [range units](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.12)
- [multipart/byteranges](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.2)